# converting to missing plus sign offset datetime string to proper datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Mostly I receive the datetime string in this format 
`d_string = '2019-03-25 15:30:00+00:00'` and I can convert to proper datetime by using

```
date_converted = datetime.strptime(d_string , '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
```

But sometime, I receive date string like this `'2019-03-25 15:30:00 00:00'` where there is no `plus` sign anymore. How can I validate this type of datestring to proper `datetime` format ? I could always add the plus sign from the last 4th position in the datestring and do the validation, but this doesn't look a better solution.

Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the `00:00` at the end, you may add the `+` to match the required pattern, this is how you can do it

```
if re.fullmatch(r"[\d-]{10} [\d:]{8} [\d:]{5}", value):
    value = re.sub(r"(?<=[\d:]{8})( )(?=[\d:]{5})", "+", value)
```

---

Giving

```
values = ['2019-03-25 15:30:00+00:00', '2019-03-25 15:30:00 00:00']
for value in values:
    if re.fullmatch(r"[\d-]{10} [\d:]{8} [\d:]{5}", value):
        value = re.sub(r"(?<=[\d:]{8})( )(?=[\d:]{5})", "+", value)
    date_converted = datetime.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
    print(date_converted)
```